# Oracle SQL Developer - How To Generate ER Diagram

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, erd

I have created a database using Oracle SQL Developer, but I am struggling to create an ERD from the database model. Can someone please help me with this? I am using version 4 of Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 3):

A very good choice is the Data Modeler in SQL Developer. A step by step guide is this one:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/saternos-datamodeler-099636.html

This will provide you a complete diagram of the whole database or selected tables in a very simple and easy way. I found this one as well:

http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/how-to-generate-an-erd-for-selected-tables-in-sql-developer/